# Good collection for keeping track of characters

Tags: java, collections

Just a general question (and I'm sort of new to java) but what would be a good collection that I could add objects to, and keep track of how many of each I've added? For example, if I added the alphabet a character at a time, it would have 26 different characters, and an associated value of 1 for each. Likewise, adding 'z' 10 times would have z with an associated 10. Suggestions? The name "hashtable" had sounded promising, but I don't think I want to use that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use a special data structure as simply using a HashMap should work well.  When adding a char, myChar, you call get(myChar), and if null, create a new item for the map for that Character with an Integer value of 1.  If the Map returns an Integer, simply add one to it, and then put it back into the Map.

Comment: I'll stick to the standard library and make Hashmap work for me. Thanks much :)

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is a Dictionary. The key would be the ASCII value of the character, and the value would be the number of times it is used. Not necessarily the most efficient way to do it, but it is one of the easiest.

You could also do it with a single array, and offset the value 0 to be the first ASCII character.

If you want an extremely fast implementation, a HashMap is actually a very good idea.

For concurrency, you can use a ConcurrentHashMap.

Comment: HashMap is the more recent implementation of it in Collections.

Comment: Hashtable is obsolete. Use HashMap instead. If thread-safety is of concern, then use ConcurrentHashMap.

Answer (score 0):

[Multiset](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset) is the data structure for this purpose. [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html) has a implementation of it.

```
Multiset<Character> charFrequency=HashMultiset.create();
charFrequency.add(char1);
charFrequency.add(char1);
charFrequency.count(char1)
```

Comment: this would take ridiculous amounts of memory. Instead of storing all occurrences of a character, you should just have a counter for each character, so you only take 26 spots instead of millions when the count gets high.

Comment: @Darkhydro why would it take more memory? I think multiset doesnt store all duplicate elements

Comment: i assume by its name that it uses sets. this means it isn't storing a counter. If it eliminates duplicates, then you can't count the number of a certain character you added, and if it doesn't eliminate duplicates then you are using lots of memory.

Comment: @Darkhydro: Don't assume by name, look at the implementations. (The documentations of the classes unfortunately don't give much complexity guarantees, but `HashMultiSet` says "uses a HashMap", so we can suppose they are doing it intelligently. Most implementations are based on [AbstractMapBasedMultiset](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/src/com/google/common/collect/AbstractMapBasedMultiset.java), and this uses a Map<E, AtomicInteger> to store the counts. (The individual classes differ only by what Map implementation is used here.)